# sync bibtex library with new google scholar library

Tags: python, bibtex, google-scholar

Is there a simple way to synchronize my local bibtex file with the new "My Library" in google scholar? In other words, I'm looking for a way to generate a bibtex file from my scholar library without exporting each entry of the list.